# Можно ли установить два разных движка на одном сервере?

Tags: joomla, xampp, wordpress

Можно ли установить 2 разных движка на xamp сервер?

Я имею ввиду WordPress и Joomla.

Comment: Можно, ну вопрос - зачем? 

Comment: 1) Чтобы не поднимать по серваку на каждый забытый богом сайт (безотносительно xamp'a)
2) Чтобы девелопить на локалке в удовольствие

Answer (score 1):

Можно. И не только 2. И не только те, что вы перечислили.